# Bootstrap css is not working on my Prestashop page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, prestashop

I'm working on a website made with Prestashop, version 1.7.5.2. I noticed Bootstrap classes (`row and col`) weren't working in my code. I tried to link Bootstrap manually in `head.tpl` file, but it didn't work. In a Prestashop forum, someone told me that Prestashop is already based in Bootstrap. So why is it like I'm not using `row` and `col` classes in my code? I'm not using any Prestashop editors, just copying and pasting my `html` code in the Source code section of the page which I'm editing. I also noticed that if I opened the Page Inspector and linked Bootstrap there with a CDN, it worked.

I show you what I already tried to link Bootstrap in `head.tpl`:

1. I tried this after uploading bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css to the server. The "include file" line already came in the `head.tpl` code. I also tried this using a CDN:

```
{block name='stylesheets'} 
    {include file="_partials/stylesheets.tpl" stylesheets=$stylesheets} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mi-dominio.com/themes/modez/assets/css/bootstrap.css"> 
{/block}
```

I also tried pasting the `link` tag in the `stylesheets.tpl` file.

2.

```
{block name='stylesheets'}
    {include file="_partials/stylesheets.tpl" stylesheets=$stylesheets} 
    {include file="_partials/bootstrap.css" stylesheets=$stylesheets} 
{/block}
```

3.

```
{block name='stylesheets'}
    {include file="_partials/stylesheets.tpl" stylesheets=$stylesheets} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$base_dir}bootstrap.css"> 
{/block}
```

This is the first time I'm using Prestashop, I've looked everywhere for an answer, I don't know what else to try. This is for a job project and I'm desperate. If you could help me, I would thank you eternally.

Comment: check page source and find link of bootstrap css and js files and go to the link. Lets check if its right path or not?

Comment: @Sachin thank you for your answer, it turned out I solved the problem using the module Content box, which allows you to link any file in the head of the website. Anyway, I got so sick of Prestashop that my boss suggested switching to WordPress, which I understand a little better. Sigh... I miss the times when you just wrote your html, CSS and JS code in your text editor... Damn CMSs.